# How would I render a list of custom object type in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, frontend

I have a List in java. The custom object has three fields, The title, Instructions, Data. I want to be able to render the list in a meaningful way using angularjs. I'd like to have the title at the top then the Instructions just above the Data which would be wrapped in a box for each CustomObject in the list. I am very new to front end and have never used Angularjs before.

I am using Angular1. I was initially passing it as a ginormous string, now I have a list I can see that the list gets to the frontend and can see the contents of the list. It's just not displayed in a readable/meaningful way. I want the list to be sectioned vertically for each CustomObject. Each CustomObject section should have a title at the top, followed by the instructions, and then a box wrapper around the Data. 
The Java class is as such:

```
class CustomObject{
  String title;
  String Instructions;
  String Data;
}
```

I want it to look like:

```
1. Title A
   Instructions A
   --------
   |Data A|   
   --------
2. Title B
   Instructions B
   --------
   |Data B |
   --------
```

Comment: I assume that you have a REST API or a JSON that expose that information from java right ?

Comment: Please provide the code that demonstrates what you tried, how your data looks like, how you want it to look like. Also is the question about Angular1 or Angular2?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Added more info to the Question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let item in customObjects">
    <div>Title {{item.title}}</div>
    <div>Instructions {{item.Instructions}}</div>
    <div>Data {{item.Data}}</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck The question is still quite unclear. I wait for feedback and then I'll update it.

Comment: It didn't like *ngFor very much. It worked with ng-repeat.

Comment: You had the Angular2 tag added initially